# Check if there some part of sting in array angular 6

Tags: angular

I have some array like this

```
  channelArray: Array<string> = ['VAT', 'HEAD'];
```

I am trying to check if there some part of string exist in array like this

```
const string = 'KolikoMitoTrebVATDaBude';
const url = this.channelArray.find(x => x === string);
```

And i am always get FALSE, i dont know whay it does not check, in this case **VAT**,
Or does it only check by full string name?

Comment: `Or does it only check by full string name?` yes

Comment: Hi Miomir, perhaps as a test try x.indexOf(string) > -1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
const url = this.channelArray.some(
    x => string.includes(x)
);
```

Comment: also it's a string comparison not finding an array element

Comment: Seeing the Q is tagged as Angular, browser support isn’t really an issue here. The .some combined with .includes is a fine answer.

Comment: @MikeOne this is not true, at least it does not work for  IE 11, `ERROR Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

`

Comment: @ABOS It should if you include the necessary polyfills for IE: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: @MikeOne, yes, that comes at a price. it is not supported by default. That is why indexOf is always a safe option.